# Adding a linestring in Rshiny/Leaflet with st_read

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, spatial, polyline

I hava a problem and I don't know where it comes from. I have a large shapefile. For a better perfomance I try to load data with `st_read()` from `sf package`. The [official documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/) states that it should be very easy to integrate the shapefile into leaflet/shiny. Nevertheless, it does not work.

```
Error message: *missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed*
```

It works with `rgdal`, but the performance is not so good.

I hope that someone can help me out.

small [TestData](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vqpw8g80g7bkkeg/AABNkXua74AQlsvgOZJnUCYCa?dl=0)

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)

shapefile <- st_read("pathToshape")

shinyApp(
  ui <-fluidRow(
    column(8,leafletOutput("map", height="600px"))
  ),

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng=16.357795000076294, lat=48.194883921677935, zoom = 15) %>%
      addPolylines(data=shapefile, layerId = shapefile$id, group = shapefile$zeitver, color="red", weight=3,opacity=1)
  })
})
```